# Помогите с приложением

Tags: синтаксис

Стена- крепость, не пропускает врага к нам.
будет ли стена- крепость приложением?

Answer (score 1):

***Стена — крепость: не пропускает врага к нам.***

Если оставить знак после слова крепость, то получается, что приложения здесь нет. Есть подлежащее *стена* и сказуемое *крепость*.

Если знак после слова *крепость* убрать, то приложение появляется: *стена* (какая?) *крепость*.

***Стена - крепость не пропускает врага к нам.***

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере приложением является не все словосочетания в целом, а только "крепость". "Стена" в данном случае является определяемым словом.

Подробнее о том, как разграничить приложение от определяемого слова, см. здесь: [Разграничение определяемого слова и приложения](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/213-prilogenie.html)

Answer (score 0):

1) **Вариант без приложения (запятая ставится):**

**Стена — крепость, не пропускает врага к нам.**

Стена — подлежащее, крепость — сказуемое, приложения нет.

В этом случае причинно-следственные отношения не обозначены, второе предложение распространяет содержание первого (тогда ставится запятая, а не двоеточие)

2) **Вариант с приложением (нет запятой):**

**Стена-крепость не пропускает врага к нам.**

Стена — определяемое существительное, крепость — **приложение**, всё сочетание в роли подлежащего.

Приложение — это **определение,** выраженное существительным (сравнить: крепостная стена).

Приложение при дефисном написании словосочетания стоит **на втором месте.**

Comment: А чем объясняется запятая в этом предложении?

Comment: Серж, но я уже написала чем. Предложения с причинно-следственной связью мы можем оформить тремя способами. Тире указывает на наличие взаимообусловленности между предложениями. Двоеточие показывает направление связи: следствие - причина. А запятая взаимообусловленность не обозначает вообще. Если нет перечислительной интонации, то отношения между предложениями неоднородные, при этом второе предложение продолжает (распространяет) тему первого. Такое оформление в текстах - обычное дело, иначе бы мы "утонули" бы в этих тире и двоеточиях,. ведь взаимосвязанные отношения встречаются часто.

Comment: Ну да. У вас, если не ошибаюсь, в первоначальном варианте говорилось только о причинно-следственных отношениях. Наверное, тире спутал с дефисом.